# Extending/modifying commands from cool package

Tags: math-mode

I started to use the `cool` package for my maths, especially for integrals, but also for trigonometric functions. I would like to get things like a sine-square function, for example, using a code like `\Sin[2]{x}` yielding `sin²(x)`. Also, I would like to add a `sinc` function, e.g. I know I could simply redefine the `\Sin` command but it would like to keep it consistent with the `cool` package.

Following the `cool` package implementation documentation [1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cool/cool.pdf) stupidly I've tried the following which is not working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cool}
\renewcommand{\Sin}[2][]{\sin^{#1}\COOL@decide@paren{Sin}{#2}}
\newcommand{\COOL@notation@SincParen}{p}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SincSymb}{Si}
\newcommand{\Sinc}[1]{\SincSymb\COOL@decide@paren{Sinc}{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \Sin{x} \\ % should produce the normal cool sin
    \Sin[2]{x} \\ % should produce sin^2
    \Sinc{x} % should produce sinc
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Of course, the next step would be to make also `sinc²` possible.

How is any of this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you forgot `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; then it's straighforward:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cool}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Sin}[2][]{%
  \sin\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi\COOL@decide@paren{Sin}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\COOL@notation@SincParen}{p}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\newcommand{\Sinc}[2][]{%
  \sinc\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else^{#1}\fi\COOL@decide@paren{Sinc}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Sin{x}    \\ % should produce the normal cool sin
\Sin[2]{x} \\ % should produce sin^2
\Sinc{x}   \\ % should produce sinc
\Sinc[2]{x}   % should produce sinc^2
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure where the advantage over `\sinc^{2}(x)` is.

[image]

Comment: oh right, I've never written own TeX commands using @ before. Thanks a lot!
The difference between \sinc and \Sinc as defined above is a) that I might be able to change the parantheses in a consistent way, b) that they automatically change size with the content and c) I was thinking about implementing more commands in the cool package style which might profit more from the code, but sinc was an easy example.

Comment: @riddleculous Well, I just write `\sin^2x` without parentheses, as it has been common for about four centuries. `;-)`

Comment: I agree, that is a method I am aware of ;) , but in my case, x is often a more complicated expression like a sum or product which makes parantheses useful. In the end, as I said, it also helps me to define other operators and functions that I use and that have a variable number of arguments. Sin and x were just chosen for simplicity. In the end it was that old \makeatletter problem